# Visual Studio destroys Riot.js expressions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, riot.js

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.5 for building an ASP.NET MVC application with a Riot.js frontend. Whenever I edit one of my riot tag files, Visual Studio's autocorrect or code formatter destroys my code, which is really annyoing. An example: when I have something like this:

```
<mytag if={station.type==9} station={station}></mytag>
```

any sooner or later moment VS will change that to

```
<mytag if={station.type = =9} station={station}></mytag>
```

Now this code won't run cleanly anymore, of course. As far as I can say I think this happens whenever you copy and paste something, it also happens when you explicitly press CTRL-K-D in order to auto-format the document. What can I do to prevent this?